# Cannot INSERT NULL into Column on Remove

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm executing a `Remove()` using Entity Framework. When I try to run `SaveChanges()`, I'm told that I can't insert NULL into a column that doesn't allow it. This is strange to me, since I'm not doing any `INSERT`, and I checked each of the 30 existing entries to find that it shouldn't be trying to save the table with null in that column.

Here is the code in question:

```
var user = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
if (user != null)
{
    var itemsToRemove = user.ItemXrefs.Where(i => !itemIDs.Contains(i.ItemID)).ToList();

    foreach (var xref in itemsToRemove)
    {
        user.ItemXrefs.Remove(xref);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    //...
}
```

Comment: can you provide the actual exception and the POCO classes involved?  It the error occurring on the entity that's being deleted from or a related entity?

Comment: It's a little confusing that you're querying `user.ItemXfefs` and then removing the results from `user.Items`. Shouldn't you be removing items from the same collection that you're querying them? Or at least verifying that `user.Items` contains the item you're removing?

Comment: @RufusL That was a mistake when simplifying my code for this question - fixed it.

Comment: I bet this has to do with a required relationship (NOT NULL foreign key column). Do you want to just remove the relationship, or delete the entity?

Comment: Just remove the relationship. As the name implies, it's definitely a linking ("cross-reference") table, so I'm just looking to delete that entry from the linking table (without touching the two entities being linked).

Comment: The weird part of it being a NOT NULL foreign key issue is that there weren't any NULL values in the table right before `SaveChanges()` ran.

Comment: So this is for a many-to-many relationship..? Does the ItemXref entity have its own primary key, or is the primary key a composite of the 2 tables it links together? Go ahead and post the code for the ItemXref entity, the User entity, and the Item entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
itemXrefSet = db.Set<ItemXref>();
foreach (var xref in itemsToRemove)
{
    itemXrefSet.Remove(xref);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

This should delete the cross-referencing entity from the gerund table as well as the relationship between the two entities it links together.

The reason you ran into an error the way you tried to do it was because EntityFramework thought you just wanted to remove the relationship without removing the related entity. When EF does this it tries to set the foreign key column in the dependent table to NULL. The way around this is to either relate the table row with another user by changing the UserId column value, or deleting the table row, since you can't set a required column value to NULL.